# Импорт только переменных

Tags: php, переменные

Добрый день, у меня такой вопрос:
Есть php-скрипты и переменные из одного должны использоваться в другом, но возникает проблема, когда я импортирую так

```
  include  'catalog.php';
```

или же

```
  require  ('catalog.php');
```

То естественно импортируется все содержимое скрипта, а есть ли возможность импортировать только переменные?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А какова цель таких ограничений?

Comment: нужно вывести значения некоторых переменных на html-страницу, типа "всего у нас 50 чайников" как-то так, без всего остального там если просто заинклудить, то там тогда много лишнего будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Создайте отдельный скрипт variables и импортируйте его в оба файла.
А вообще, точка входа должна быть по возможности одна. Остальные файлы должны состоять из функций/классов/данных. То бишь, факт подключения не обязывал бы этот код исполняться. Тогда и проблем подобных не будет.

Comment: Спасибо! Сам думал так сделать, но  казалось, что есть встроенные функции.